# How can I make list or set translatable using gettext?

Tags: python, django, gettext

I have some structure in Python:

```
> gender=( ('0','woman'), ('1','man') )
```

I want to translate it before I will display it in Django template. Unfortunately, below solution doesn't work:

```
> from django.utils.translation import
> ugettext_lazy as _
> 
> gender=( ('0',_('woman')),
> ('1',_('man')) )
```

What shall I do to translate this? I read [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#deferred-translations), but I can't understand what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
gender=( ('0',_('woman')), ('1',_('man')) )
```

When you import gettext:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

you need to wrap the string in gettext function:

```
_('some_string')
```

If underscore is confiusing you, this is same as writing:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
ugettext_lazy('some_string')
```

but using `_` is shorter.

After you have marked strings for translation call [makemessages](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#makemessages) django command.

Comment: I know it, I do like you, but in my post underscore did not display, I don't know why.
Some simply text I can translate but I can't translate list or others structures.

Comment: ooh, sorry then... :), are using `gender` for choices in models? This seems to work ok for me. What is the exact problem? `woman` and `man` don't appear in *.po files?

Comment: appear there, I made translation and compiled, but still I see english version.

Comment: So the strings appears in generated *.po but don't appear on site? Have you tried to changed the language in settings?

Comment: OK, I tried use ugettext_lazy and it makes diffrent it is work :)
Before I was useing ugettext, in my first post I paste wrong code (ugettext_lazy)...
Sorry for problems and thanks